# pip install from git repository error on url with hash symbol

Tags: python, pip

I want to **install python package** from **remote git repository** (say using azure devops, github, or any other) via **pip**. Also I want to specify a **branch** to install, so I type

```
pip install git+https://dev.azure.com/repository@branch
```

But my branch contains **# (hash) symbol** and pip just skip everything after it.

Example:
pip install git+https://dev.azure.com/repository@branch/#name-with-hash

Error message:

```
...
Running command git checkout -q branch/
error: pathspec 'branch/' did not match any file(s) known to git
...
```

I have tried to put url to quotes, encode full url or its parts but still I can not overcome this # symbol.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git itself. You just need to get the `#` character past whatever it is (it's not Git!) that is stripping it, and the remainder of the line, out. Figure out what that is and find out how to get the character past that program. In the future, consider avoiding such branch names so as to sidestep the problem entirely.

Comment: @torek I tried all possible ways to escape `#` in `pip install -v git+file:///path/test/.git@master#test` — single/double quotes, `%23` percent encoding — nothing helped. `pip` sees the branch `master` but not the hash character (and everything after it). Also `@` makes problems. Any other character could be escaped but not `#` or `@`. I suspect a bug in `pip` parser.

Comment: @phd: could be, although something as widely used as pip *should* have a workaround. Should does not mean will/does, alas.

Comment: @torek I reported the bug: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10226